# PIG LOAD filename

Tags: apache-pig

I am just trying to load an unstructured input file and add the filename. So what I want to get is two fields :
filename:chararray, inputrow:chararray.

I can load the filename if I have a field delimiter using pigstorage(';','-tagfile') but I do not want to delimit fields at this point I just want the string and the filename. How can I do this ?

B

Comment: Could you add some sample input and the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

The way to load in files without applying a delimiter, is to choose a delimiter that does not (cannot) occur in the file.

For example, if your file is separated by `;` and cannot contain tabs `\t` you could do:

```
pigstorage('\t','-tagfile')
```